# How to add multiple markers in google map using angular google map api

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am writing an angular 4 web application and I want to add multiple markers based on lattitude and longitude.

Array of lattitude and longitude of cities,

```
cities = [
    {lat: 12.972442, longi: 77.580643},
    {lat: 12.972234, longi: 77.580233},
    {lat: 12.972123, longi: 77.580623}
  ];
```

in my template,

```
 <div  id="map">
      <agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom">
        <agm-marker  [iconUrl]="iconUrl" [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
      </agm-map>
      </div>
```

And in onInit() function,

```
public latitude: number;
public longitude: number;
    for ( let city of this.cities ) {
      this.latitude = city.lat;
      this.longitude = city.longi;
    }
```

I think i am wrong, but i am not getting any other ideas, please help me .
Adding edits related to new ideas but map is not showing now, here are the change,
Added a new coordinate class as follows,

```
export class Coordinate {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;

    constructor(lat, lng) {
        this.latitude = lat;
        this.longitude = lng;
    }
}
```

Upadated  in html,

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" (ngModel)="coordinates" [zoom]="zoom">
        <agm-marker *ngFor="let marker of coordinates" [iconUrl]="iconUrl" [latitude]="marker.latitude" [longitude]="marker.latitude"></agm-marker>
    </agm-map>
```

Changes in ngOnInit(),

```
 for ( let city of this.cities ) {
      const loc = new Coordinate(city.lat, city.longi);
      this.coordinates.push(loc);
    }
```

But still, the markers are not adding, Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you do that in onInit() you're just changing `this.latitude` and `this.longitude` fields to the latitude and longitude of the last city in the array of cities. You have just one latitude/longitude pair and you need an array of them (for multiple coordinates).

You should probably first have a class for storing both of them in the same object:

```
class Coordinate {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;

    constructor(lat, lng) {
        this.latitude = lat;
        this.longitude = lng;
    }
}
```

Then you can create an array of Coordinates like so:

```
// component fields
public coordinates: Coordinate[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    for ( let city of this.cities ) {
        this.coordinates.push(new Coordinate(city.latitude, city.longitude));
    }
}
```

And in the template, `*ngFor` your markers, like so:

```
<div id="map">
    <agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom">
        <agm-marker *ngFor="let marker of coordinates" [iconUrl]="iconUrl" [latitude]="marker.latitude" [longitude]="marker.longitude"></agm-marker>
    </agm-map>
</div>
```

See if that helps!

Comment: What is not working? Could you be a little less specific? Did you just copy and paste the code or actually tried to understand it and implement it yourself? Try to make it working and, if you can not, ask a question with a valid error/logic mistake, where is it happening and what was the expected outcome. I can not see a way of me helping you just by "it is not working" sentence, it means literally nothing to me.

Comment: i mean, i have done exactly you suggested, created extra coordinate class and created array of objects of that class and used in ngm-marker. But when i ran, no marker displayed and no message in console also.

Comment: added changes in the question, please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use position attribute

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" (ngModel)="coordinates" [zoom]="zoom">
    <agm-marker *ngFor="let city of cities" [position]="[city.lat, city.longi]" [iconUrl]="iconUrl" ></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your html file add this inside your agm-map tags (also I would try this without the custom icon at first to make sure they are showing up on the map):

```
<agm-marker 
*ngFor="let x of cities; let i = index"
[latitude]="x.lat"
[longitude]="x.longi"
[iconUrl]="iconUrl"
>
</agm-marker>
```